# Garbage Collection in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management

So I'm making a client program for a MySQL database for a class and I have a few variables declared at the top of my form class that I use and reuse throughout the lifespan of the form. Every time the variables get used, I'm simply doing something like:

```
variableName = new VariableClass();
```

and then using it, primarily with DataSets/Tables. What I'm wondering is should I be explicitly freeing the memory before making another call to new or does C# take care of that for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly free .Net objects in C#.  It runs on the CLR which is a garbage collected environment and hence the items will be cleaned up for you.

That being said ... it's unclear from your question if you are allocating these as fields or locals.  If you are allocating them in fields and only using them in one function then you should move that declaration to a local.  While the memory won't leak you will be holding onto the objects for significantly longer than is needed.  This unnecessarily increases the memory footprint of your application.

Comment: The primary way these DataSets/Tables are used is that I retrieve a list of names from a table in my DB and use them to populate dropdown menus, and later build SQL queries when the user selects say, a patient name from a dropdown and wants to see the associated medical history or insurance information. EDIT: That in mind, would it be better to retrieve those names every time I need them, or just keep them the way I have it, wher eI fetch them once and resuse.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what the class of the variables does. If it uses resources that require disposal or if it uses unmanaged resources, you should implement IDisposable and ensure that they are disposed of correctly. If not, you can rely on the garbage collector to do its thing.